# Java in Classic ASP

Tags: java, asp-classic, iis-7

Is it still possible to use Java in Classic ASP (IIS 7.* / Windows) via Java Moniker as is demonstrated at http://cephas.net/blog/2004/03/15/scripting-in-asp-with-java/? (and http://thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch11f.htm and https://hq.lojcomm.com.br/java/Interop.class.asp).

I cannot make it work from IIS 8.5 (or from dektop VbScript) in my Windows 10 with Java 1.8.0_131 installed in C:\Program Files\Java.

I get all the time: error'800401e4' with no other clarifications in the first line:

```
set Java_Date = getObject("java:java.util.Date")
response.write( Java_Date.toString() )
```

and the same error comes if I try to use NetBeans-compiled custom class:

```
set Java_Greeter = getObject("java:omatestit.Hello")


public class Hello
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //do nothing - this will keep us from getting a compile error
 }

  public String SayHello()
  {
   return "Hello Geek";
  }
}
```

which locates in: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\win32\TrustLib\omatestit\Hello.class"

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with previous settings?

Comment: As far as I know, Java support in Classic ASP was through J++, which Micorsoft discontinued in 2004
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already thought that nobody cares about the old subject any more. You are most probably right about this, that Java is not supported any more in Classic ASP on windows, at least it seems to be so on the basis of my tests.